# Contact Management Plugin suggestions, or tutorials/resources recommendations

Tags: plugin-recommendation, users, newsletter, management

I will soon be building a site for a local Non-Profit Art Community, and they would like a to have a powerful **contact/member management system** that can do these key things:

1. Store User Contact info (Address, Phone, Email, Website, regdate, etc.)
2. Synchronize with a newsletter mailing service, their preference is Emma. (Alternatively, the desired plugin could handle the newsletters internally)
3. Tag users with multiple tags, example would be Artist, Volunteer, Member.
4. Track membership and expiry, as well as payment history for Members.
5. Hopefully use the built-in Wordpress User area of the admin.

My question is, can anyone recommend a plugin that can get me all the way, or part of the way there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddypress will probably help you too. I guess you'll want your community members to interact?

Also just [search the wordpress.org plugins repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), for "membership" or "members" plugins to compare with.

The [plugin "s2member"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/), for example, is very popular.

Comment: Plain links are considered "poor quality" and automatically flagged by the "community user"-bot. Please always add context. For e.g. explain what each plugin does, how it is coded, how it can be used in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout these plugins.

*Links to the official wp.org repository:*

- [s2member](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/)
- [subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/)
- [Unlimited Contact Info](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unlimited-contact-info/)

Comment: Plain links are considered "poor quality" and automatically flagged by the "community user"-bot. Please always add context. For e.g. explain what each plugin does, how it is coded, how it can be used in the context of the question. Please go back and edit your answer. Thanks.